# how create PasswordHash asp identity in frm (winForms) o generate PasswordHash

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, winforms, asp.net-identity, identity

good day, you could help me indicating how the PasswordHash genre that generates autmaticamente identity templates, I need to make a web service that responds tru if the field and the BD equals the parameter sent (pass)

as I call the template that creates asp.net it is:

```
Protected Sub LogIn(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        If IsValid Then
            ' Validate the user password
            Dim manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager(Of ApplicationUserManager)()
            Dim signinManager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager(Of ApplicationSignInManager)()

            ' This doen't count login failures towards account lockout
            ' To enable password failures to trigger lockout, change to shouldLockout := True
            Dim result = signinManager.PasswordSignIn(Email.Text, Password.Text, RememberMe.Checked, shouldLockout:=True)

            Select Case result
                Case SignInStatus.Success
                    IdentityHelper.RedirectToReturnUrl(Request.QueryString("ReturnUrl"), Response)
                    Exit Select
                Case SignInStatus.LockedOut
                    Response.Redirect("/Account/Lockout")
                    Exit Select
                Case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification
                    Response.Redirect(String.Format("/Account/TwoFactorAuthenticationSignIn?ReturnUrl={0}&RememberMe={1}",
                                                    Request.QueryString("ReturnUrl"),
                                                    RememberMe.Checked),
                                      True)
                    Exit Select
                Case Else
                    FailureText.Text = "Intento inválido de inicio de sesión"
                    ErrorMessage.Visible = True
                    Exit Select
            End Select
        End If
    End Sub
```

I need to create the encryption password to compare it with that of BD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [class](https://aspnetidentity.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/Crypto.cs) is doing the password hashing in Identity framework.

Answer (score 1):

Use user manager's `PasswordHasher` property to generate hashed password and compare it with stored data:

```
 var userManager=HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUSerManager>();
 string hashedPassword=userManager.PasswordHasher.HashPassword("myPass");
```